# Connect WCF with Silverlight

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, connection

I created a web service vith WCF and i want to use it in a silverlight project.
Here is my web.config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>

 <system.web>
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
 </system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfig">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:2252/Service1"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
      contract="DataRetrieverReference.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
</client>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
       <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and      remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
       <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
       <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value    below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>     
  </configuration>
```

Here is my C# code to get data from web service.But it always returns null.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:2252/Service1");
        var myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, endpoint);

        IService1 client = null;
        Person person = null;
        try
        {
            client = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();

        }
        catch
        { 

        }
        person = client.GetPersonbyId(textBox1.Text);
        name.Text = person.nameValue;
        surname.Text = person.surnameValue;
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        Person GetPersonbyId(string id);
        // TODO: Add your service operations here


    }
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Are you getting any error (if so which)? else what appears to be 'not' working?

Comment: When i tried to call the getPersonByID function in wcf project (in Test Client) it works but in silverlight project i am getting a null value.I have no exception or something.

Comment: Is your person object decorated with the DataContract/DataMember attributes? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't see [OperationContract] above GetPersonById